# Flash drive not recognised - Unknown device: "Voyager Mini 3.0"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, flash-memory

I have a Retina Macbook Pro and have just received 6 x Voyager Mini USB 3.0 64GB drives (as gifts for colleagues). I've tried 3 of the drives and while they work in Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.3), they do not come up in Finder or Disk Util on OS X. I've tried them in several machines:

1) MacBook Pro Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013 (MacbookPro10,2) - OS X 10.8 5
2) MacBook Pro (MacbookPro8,1) - OS X 10.6.8
3) MacBook Pro (MacbookPro5,5) - OS X 10.8.3

I tried reformatting one to FAT32 to see if that changed anything, but I'm getting the same result. I have also tried formatting with the SDFormat tool on Windows (to exfat though, not ntfs) and this had no effect.

I have downloaded and installed IOUSBFamily with logging enabled. Using "USB Prober.app" I was able to get the below information. It seems that the OS is seeing the drive, but doesn't know what to make of it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Appropriate section from "USB Bus Probe":

```
Super Speed device @ 3 (0x15300000): .............................................   Unknown device: "Voyager Mini 3.0"
    Port Information:   0x101a
           Not Captive
           Attached to Root Hub
           External Device
           Connected
           Enabled
           Connected to External Port
    Number Of Endpoints (includes EP0):   
        Total Endpoints for Configuration 1 (unconfigured):   3
    Device Descriptor   
        Descriptor Version Number:   0x0300
        Device Class:   8   (Unknown)
        Device Subclass:   6
        Device Protocol:   80
        Device MaxPacketSize:   9
        Device VendorID/ProductID:   0x1B1C/0x1A0C   (CORSAIR MEMORY INC.)
        Device Version Number:   0x0110
        Number of Configurations:   1
        Manufacturer String:   1 "Corsair"
        Product String:   2 "Voyager Mini 3.0"
        Serial Number String:   3 "07083BCC9F560866"
    BOS Descriptor   
        Length (and contents):   22
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0000: 05 0F 16 00 02 07 10 02  02 00 00 00 0A 10 03 00  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0010: 0E 00 02 0A FF 07 
        Number of Capability Descriptors:   2
            USB 2.0 Extension:   2
                bmAttributes:   0x00000002
                   Bit 1:  Link Power Management supported
            SuperSpeed USB Device:   3
                bmAttributes:   0x00000000
                wSpeedsSupported:   0x000e
                   Bit 1:  Full Speed supported
                   Bit 2:  High Speed supported
                   Bit 3:  Super Speed (5Gbps) supported
                bFunctionalitySupport:   0x0002:  Full Speed and above
                bU1ExitLat:   Less than 10 µs
                wU2ExitLat:   Less than 2047 µs
    Current configuration:   0 (unconfigured)
    Configuration Descriptor   
        Length (and contents):   44
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0000: 09 02 2C 00 01 01 00 80  3F 09 04 00 00 02 08 06  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0010: 50 00 07 05 81 02 00 04  00 06 30 03 00 00 00 07  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0020: 05 02 02 00 04 00 06 30  03 00 00 00 
        Number of Interfaces:   1
        Configuration Value:   1
        Attributes:   0x80 (bus-powered)
        MaxPower:   504 mA
        Interface #0 - Mass Storage/SCSI   
            Alternate Setting   0
            Number of Endpoints   2
            Interface Class:   8   (Mass Storage)
            Interface Subclass;   6   (SCSI)
            Interface Protocol:   80   (Bulk Only)
            Endpoint 0x81 - Bulk Input   
                Address:   0x81  (IN)
                Attributes:   0x02  (Bulk)
                Max Packet Size:   1024
                SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion   
                    bMaxBurst:   3
                    bmAttributes:   0 (1 MaxStreams)
            Endpoint 0x02 - Bulk Output   
                Address:   0x02  (OUT)
                Attributes:   0x02  (Bulk)
                Max Packet Size:   1024
                SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion   
                    bMaxBurst:   3
                    bmAttributes:   0 (1 MaxStreams)
```

Level 3 log while plugging in the drive:

```
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [2]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::PollInterrupts - deferring checking for RHStatus until we are running again
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [2]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::WakeControllerFromDoze _myPowerState: 3
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(638), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803ad44300) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb180)
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::GetRootHubPortStatus port: 7, portSC: 0x00021203, status: 0x8203, change: 0x0000, portIsDebouncing: 1
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(639), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.166  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803adafe00) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb000)
Dec 11 11:15:53.199  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::InterruptReadHandler error kIOReturnAborted. Try again.
Dec 11 11:15:53.199  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(640), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.199  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803ad44300) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb180)
Dec 11 11:15:53.199  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::InterruptReadHandler error kIOReturnAborted (expected)
Dec 11 11:15:53.298  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::GetRootHubPortStatus port: 7, portSC: 0x00021203, status: 0x8203, change: 0x0001, portIsDebouncing: 1
Dec 11 11:15:53.299  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMRootHubStatusChange got bitmap (0x80)
Dec 11 11:15:53.299  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(+) now (1)
Dec 11 11:15:53.299  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::GetRootHubPortStatus port: 7, portSC: 0x00001203, status: 0x0203, change: 0x0000, portIsDebouncing: 0
Dec 11 11:15:53.299  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(648), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.299  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803adafe00) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb180)
Dec 11 11:15:53.332  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::HubAreAllPortsDisconnectedOrSuspended - port 3 still initing, status changing, or adding a device (0/1/0)
Dec 11 11:15:53.332  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::InterruptReadHandler error kIOReturnAborted (expected)
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(+) now (2)
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(-) now (1)
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(651), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803ad44300) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb180)
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(+) now (2)
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [2]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::AbandonPortCheck - waking up commandSleep
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::event type == kXHCITRB_PSCE, calling RootHubStartTimer32
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [2]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::AbandonPortCheck - waking up commandSleep
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(654), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.400  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803adafe00) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb000)
Dec 11 11:15:53.432  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::GetRootHubPortStatus port: 7, portSC: 0x00201203, status: 0x0203, change: 0x0010, portIsDebouncing: 0
Dec 11 11:15:53.432  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMRootHubStatusChange got bitmap (0x80)
Dec 11 11:15:53.432  [2]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::AbandonPortCheck - waking up commandSleep
Dec 11 11:15:53.432  [2]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::AbandonPortCheck - waking up commandSleep
Dec 11 11:15:53.432  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(+) now (3)
Dec 11 11:15:53.433  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(-) now (2)
Dec 11 11:15:53.467  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac87000]::InterruptReadHandler error kIOReturnAborted (expected)
Dec 11 11:15:53.533  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::GetRootHubPortStatus port: 7, portSC: 0x00001203, status: 0x0203, change: 0x0000, portIsDebouncing: 0
Dec 11 11:15:53.544  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIM **** - ConfigureDeviceZero maxPacketSize:9, speed:3, hub:128, adj port:7
Dec 11 11:15:53.544  [2]    -AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::AllocateAppleXHCIAsyncEndpoint 0xffffff8047c0fc00 maxPacketSize 512 maxBurst 0 mult 0
Dec 11 11:15:53.544  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateControlEndpoint - inc ConfiguredEpCount (ring0)
Dec 11 11:15:53.544  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateControlEndpoint 2 - Output context - pPhysical[0x23f000] pLogical[0xffffff8117eb5000]
Dec 11 11:15:53.544  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::AddressDevice - _devZeroPort: 7, _devZeroHub:128
Dec 11 11:15:53.544  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::AddressDevice - Port 7 speed is: 4, device speed is: 3
Dec 11 11:15:53.545  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::AddressDevice - _devZeroPort: 7, _devZeroHub:128
Dec 11 11:15:53.545  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::AddressDevice - Port 7 speed is: 4, device speed is: 3
Dec 11 11:15:53.547  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(-) now (1)
Dec 11 11:15:53.547  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMDeleteEndpoint - fn:0, ep:0, dir:3
Dec 11 11:15:53.547  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::GetSlotID - functionNumber disabled: 0
Dec 11 11:15:53.547  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateControlEndpoint 2 - currMPS == maxPacketSize: 512
Dec 11 11:15:53.548  [3]    IOUSBControllerV3(AppleUSBXHCI)[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::ChangeExternalDeviceCount - got first external device, changing assertion to ON
Dec 11 11:15:53.548  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::ChangeRaisedPowerState(-) now (0)
Dec 11 11:15:53.548  [3]    AppleUSBHub[0xffffff803ac74000]::DecrementOutstandingIO(663), outstandingIO(0), _interruptReadPending(false) - rearming read
Dec 11 11:15:53.548  [3]    AppleUSBXHCI[0xffffff80f9c9a000]::UIMCreateInterruptTransfer - root hub interrupt transfer - clearing unneeded memDesc (0xffffff803ad44300) from dmaCommand (0xffffff803acdb000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corsair support has stated that this is a bug in the firmware (v1.1) on these drives. Apparently the fix is implemented, but drives with the new firmware are not available at this stage.